# What is the replacement of mysql_query() in case of INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, deprecated

Till now I was using `mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... ");` function to insert rows in my database. This is a deprecated function now so I'm searching for a replacement. Something like `select_query("SELECT ... ");` is for `mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... ");`

Edit:
Forgot to mention, that select_query() looks like this:

```
function select_query($query) {
  global $pdo;
  $stm = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $stm->execute();
  return $stm->fetchAll();
}
```

I have a global PDO object declared in a different file.

Comment: Use *mysqli* which is somewhat similar to the *mysql* extension or PDO. See http://php.net/manual/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: The big red message in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) tells you exactly what the alternatives are: `Warning 
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. __Alternatives to this function include:
•mysqli_query()
•PDO::query()__
`

Comment: How should I create a function to insert values using PDO?

Comment: Start reading `PDO Documentation`

Comment: I have read the PDO but could not understand the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer version of every `mysql_*()` function is now their [`mysqli_*()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) counterpart. You can use them exactly the same way, but I suggest learning to do prepared statements.

You can also use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) included in PHP which is my favorite.

Comment: *"You can use them exactly the same way"* ~ no you can't. The API is significantly different

Comment: @Forien I would like to use PDO. But I don't know how to create a function like the `select_query()` for insertion. Could you please show me an example?

Comment: @Forien Thank you for pointing out that link for me, I didn't know what should I search for in the PDO Documentation.

Comment: thanks for PDO advice , just start using it after reading it from here

Answer (score 1):

Hi the easyest way is the mySqli extension

```
mysqli_query($connection, 'INSERT INTO...');
```

or:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($srv, $user, $pass, $database);
$connection->query('INSERT INTO .....');
```

**[***Read the PHP Manual about mySqli !](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Comment: I would like to use the PDO, I think it is more flexible.

Comment: PDO supports multiple databases. Mysqli only MySQL. if you only deal with MySQL the mysqli is slightly faster. PDO is more flexible if you need to work with multiple databases..... if you don't understand the documentation of PDO.... I recommend  the mysqli because it offers procedural API  (first example) that is the same as the deprecated mysql_connect().